# Are there Venn diagrams made of convex shapes for more than 6 sets?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, convex-geometry

I was wondering about the following related questions:

Is there an upper bound for the number $n$ of sets for which a two-dimensional Venn diagram can be constructed using *convex shapes* only?  What if we also require that the shapes be identical (but not necessarily symmetrically arranged)?  What about in three or more dimensions?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets) shows a 6-set Venn diagram constructed with triangles, and a 5-set one constructed with identical ellipses. Thus the answers to the first two questions must be at least 6 and 5, respectively.

Comment: According to the dynamic survey by Ruskey and Weston, there is such a Venn diagram for all integers $n$: http://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds5/ds5v3-2005/VennGeometricEJC.html#convex