# How many sets possible on a plane Venn diagram (using a convex shape for each of the participating sets)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

In the picture below I managed to draw a Venn diagram for 4 sets with ellipses delineating each of the 4 sets ($A,B,C,D$).

Is it possible to draw a Venn diagram on the plane for an arbitrary number of sets, using convex domains for each of the participating sets?

Jutst to be clear: a Venn diagram of a number of sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ must allocate some territory (with positive area) for any of the possible intersections $\left(A_{j_1} \cap \ldots \cap A_{j_m}\right)\setminus (A_{j_{m+1}}\cup\ldots \cup A_{j_n})$. A stricter requirement could be that one demands that each of these allocated regions is connected: Feel free to discuss this further restriction in your answer.

[image]

Comment: @bof No, merely a convex shape

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram

Comment: @bof The wikipedia page has some interesting material, but does it indicate to an answer to my question?

Comment: See [Are there venn diagrams made of convex shapes for more than 6 sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783587/are-there-venn-diagrams-made-of-convex-shapes-for-more-than-6-sets) which leads to the link https://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds5/ds5v3-2005/VennGeometricEJC.html#convex.  See also [Why can a venn diagram for 4 sets not be constructed with circles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/why-can-a-venn-diagram-for-4-sets-not-be-constructed-using-circles?rq=1)